# ffmpeg silenceremove on 2 track audio

Tags: ffmpeg, strip-silence

Is there any way to use silenceremove on file with 2 audio tracks, to trim silence only when the silence is on both audio tracks?

File info: .mp4 with 2 stereo audio tracks(aac)

I've already tried start_mode and stop_mode. In both states. But ffmpeg trims both tracks separately. And I need to save the sequence.

I'm trying to achieve result similar to "delete silence" function in Adobe Audition. This function trims silence only when both stereo tracks are silent. And It saves the sequence.

Comment: Is  each track mono or stereo?

Comment: Each track stereo

Comment: Two Stereo audio tracks? AAC supports up to 48 tracks, but they are not grouped or paired. So this would be 4 mono tracks? Not sure two stereo tracks is a correct configuration. please confirm?

Comment: Can you post a link to the file you are trying to process, and also a full command-line example of what you are attempting to use to process it ?